# How to change the text-style of a ListView Header

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

This is my code to only make the Header of the listView bold, but it is not working, because not only the Header, but all the items are getting bold.

```
listView.Columns[0].ListView.Font = new Font(listView.Columns[0].ListView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot change the header font. But you can change the font for each individual list item. The simple but *hacky* approach is to set `ListView.Font` to the bold font and change the font of every `ListItem.Font` to the default font.

```cs
listView.Font = _headerFont;
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
    item.Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
}
```

Alternatively for full control set the `OwnerDraw` property to `true` and handle both `DrawColumnHeader` and `DrawItem` events like below:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Font _headerFont = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView.DrawColumnHeader += DrawColumnHeader;
        listView.DrawItem += DrawItem;
    }

    private void DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw default background
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Draw text in a different font
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
            e.Header.Text,
            _headerFont,
            e.Bounds,
            SystemColors.ControlText,
            TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }

    private void DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Use defaults for Items
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

The example above shows how it works, but in a real world application you also have to draw dependent on the item's state like in the [more comprehensive example in the .NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of Christian Held, I come up with the next solution:
Put this in the constructor of the form:

```
List<ColumnHeader> columns = new List<ColumnHeader>
            {
                new ColumnHeader{Text = "ColumnOne", TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left},
                new ColumnHeader{Text = "ColumnTwo", TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left},
                new ColumnHeader{Text = "ColumnThree", TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left}
            };
MyListView.Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);
columns.ForEach(col => MyListView.Columns.Add(col));
MyListView.View = View.Details;
```

After that, when you fill with data your ListView, you must set the font for every record added:

```
foreach (MyData myData in MyDatas){
    listViewItem = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                {
                    myData.Data1,
                    myData.Data2,
                    myData.Data3
                });
     listViewItem.Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
     MyListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

And it works fine for me. If you want to change the backcolor or other things in the font of the data, just change the SystemFonts.DefaultFont for some font that you like, something like

```
var myFont = new Font(...your details here....);
```